# Android in-app billing error code - Error OR-IEH-02

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I released a new version of my Android app, along with a newly added managed in-app purchase product. However, many users are not able to make a purchase of the new product, and reported having an error code when attempting to make a purchase that says "Can't purchase. Error OR-IEH-02". 
So far we have not been able to reproduced the error as a test user. Any idea on what the error code means?

Answer (score 1):

This means payment is being denied to to Google Play's fraud risk controls. Either your users are potentially fraudulent, or Google Play is incorrectly detecting their payment method as at a very high risk of fraud. The only thing you can do is contact Google Play support through the help menu on the Play console.